# in slick.js' custom dot nav, width of active doesn't match

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

[slick official](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

I customized slick's dot navigation and made it an image.
And it was scheduled to be like this:
[image: button]

### But now

[image: why]

oops
The image of `active` should have been reduced by half, but it is not getting smaller..
In the developer tool, it was a mysterious number `10px` which was not set to`width` or `height`.

[image: ?!]

How can I invalidate this mysterious `10px`?

---

[slick.js code](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/slick/slick.js) (Link to github code)

DOM that seems to be related:

[image: in developer tool]

---

### In my mind, when hovering

[image: like this]
I want to make it feel like this.
I inserted insideBlack button in `::before` and fiddled `opacity` with `:hover`, but in my way there were no outside button left..

How to make transparency like this when insideBlack button is `hover` while leaving the outside button intact?

---

### My code

CSS

```
.pxradio {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -55px;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .pxradio li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
.pxradio li button {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border: 0;
  background: url("../img/radio-outside.svg");
  display: block;
  height: 9px;
  width: 9px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
.pxradio li button:hover, .pxradio li button:focus {
  outline: none;
 }
.pxradio li.slick-active button {
  background: url("../img/radio-insideBlack.svg");
  width: 4.5px;
  height: 4.5px;
  opacity: 1;
 }
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
  $('#carousel').slick({
    dotsClass: 'pxradio',
  });
});
```

---

### Finally

[image: this!]

Thank you very much!
Slightly customized, and eventually it looked like this.
The slight deviation of the black circle could be fixed by `backface-visibility: hidden;`.

```
.pxradio li button {
  position: relative;    /* Add */
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border: 0;
  background: url("../img/pxradio-n.svg");  /* =radio-outside.svg */
  display: block;
  height: 9px;
  width: 9px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pxradio li button:hover, .pxradio li button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.pxradio li button::before {    /* ▼ Add everything from here */
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-image: url("../img/pxradio-c.svg");    /* =radio-insideBlack.svg */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 3.5px;
  height: 3.5px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.pxradio li button:hover::before {
  opacity: .2;
}
.pxradio li.slick-active button {
  background: url("../img/pxradio-n.svg"), url("../img/pxradio-c.svg");
  background-size: 10px, 4.5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center, center;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Hey, it's me again. Do you have a link to the working web page?

Comment: @Andy Hoffman Hey! Hello again.
Because it is still local, temporary up link -> [here](https://mqs2.com/box/code/) The first visible page has this dot navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually need is to use multiple background images, which `CSS` supports [extremely well](https://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds).

> Multiple background images are specified using a comma-separated list
>   of values for the background-image property, with each value
>   generating a separate ‘background layer’. The the first value in the
>   list represents the top layer (closest to the user), with subsequent
>   layers rendered behind successively.

To line things up properly, I needed to use `10px` dimension for the outer image.

```css
.pxradio li.slick-active button {
  background-image: url(https://mqs2.com/box/code/img/pxradio-n.svg), url(https://mqs2.com/box/code/img/pxradio-c.svg);
  background-size: 10px, 4.5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center, center;
}
```

[image]

I wrote a standalone example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/312kohzq/4/).

### Update

After learning about what you wanted to do with opacity to the inner background when hovering over the button, I made some changes. Basically, I no longer use multiple backgrounds on the same element. I moved one of the background to `::before` so that I could use opacity on it without affecting the outer ring. The active button is not `position: relative` so that I center the inner dot with absolute positioning within that relative container.

This example has an `active` state that is always there, but you could easily modify your own work using this code. Notice the hover state of the `active` button.

```css
li button {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border: 0;
  background: url("https://mqs2.com/box/code/img/pxradio-n.svg");
  display: block;
  height: 9px;
  width: 9px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;  
}

li.active button {
  position: relative;
}

li.active button::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(https://mqs2.com/box/code/img/pxradio-c.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 4.5px;
  height: 4.5px;
}

li.active button:hover::before {
  opacity: .3;
}

/* Ignore */
ul { margin: 0; list-style: none; display: flex; }
li { padding-right: 1em; }
html { margin: 2em; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><button></button></li>
  <li class="active"><button></button></li>
  <li><button></button></li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvw19z2o/1/)

Comment: Thank you! :D
How can I display this small black circle image as overlapped like the first image with `active` or `hover` ?
I didn't work with `position: relative` and `position: absolute` that I know..

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you! :)
I want to make the black button look transparent when hovering (reference the added image), but I could not do it with my own power TT
I would like to do like this. How should I do?

Comment: @POP Check out the latest update. I think this is what you're after.

Comment: Oh! It use like this! Ultimately it became like the last update. I'm really thankful to you!! xD